# How to consume web service from my client?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, service, wsdl

I created 5 different types of services. A,B,C,D,E.  using Apache Axis

From single java client I will call all these 5 services and give 3 args to each service.

I created the client. like this is it right?

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;

public class ServicesCaller 
{

    String A="";
    String B="";
    String C="";

    public void services(String start,String end,String comfort)
    {
         try 
         {
            String endpoint1="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A1";
            String endpoint2="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A2";
            String endpoint3="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A3";
            String endpoint4="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A4";
            String endpoint5="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A5";

            Service service=new Service();

            Call call=(Call)service.createCall();

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint1));
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint2));
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint3));
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint4));
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint5));

            call.setOperationName(new QName("http://service.com","firstReturn"));

            String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start,end,comfort} );

         }

         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
    }
}
```

is it correct? When I run from my jsp I get this exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Deserializing parameter 'arg0':  could not find deserializer for type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}string
```

Comment: I suggest you use wsimport to have a Java client generated for your WSDL

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use an IDE to create subs for each of the Web service WSDL. after you have the stubs, just make a call to their dummy methods. this saves you a lot f time and effort.

and Secondly use the below code logic, as per your code, you wont be able to call all the WS but only the last one.

if you dont have an IDE then download Net Beans or oracle Jdev both of which are freeware and dont need licence 
if you cant do that even then WSImport is the best option that you have.

```
public class ServicesCaller 
{

    String A="";
    String B="";
    String C="";

    public void services(String start,String end,String comfort)
    {
         try 
         {
            String endpoint1="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A1";
            String endpoint2="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A2";
            String endpoint3="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A3";
            String endpoint4="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A4";
            String endpoint5="http://localhost:8080/callser/services/A5";

            Service service=new Service();

            Call call=(Call)service.createCall();

            String ret ="";
            call.setOperationName(new QName("http://service.com","allepyReturn"));

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint1));
            ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start,end,comfort} );

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint2));
            ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start,end,comfort} );

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint3));
            ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start,end,comfort} );

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint4));
            ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start,end,comfort} );

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint5));
            ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {start,end,comfort} );

         }

         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
    }
```

Comment: how to create stubs for each clients? and how to make call from each clients

Comment: lets say u have Jdev, open your project in it...include the WSDL in the project..then right click on the WSDL and click on generate web service proxy...once you do that, it takes you through a wizard and when you finish, u get all the stub classes and files generated..

repeat this for all WSDLs.

Comment: That also has the same feature, try to search generating stubs in eclipse from WSDL..every IDE provides such support..

Comment: I created client stubs. Now I have to call the client from my servlet. How to call it

Comment: I get this error again when I run my program

java.lang.InstantiationException: com.service.BusService

Comment: please share stack trace and also some of the details of the WSDL/Webservice like version and type of Webservice
 
probably you are facing error in marshaling and unmarshaling..